# pyTelegramBotAPI: bot stops running after about 1 hour on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, bots, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I can't find a solution. I'm hosting a telegram bot in python with the library *pyTelegramBotAPI* on ***Heroku***, my code works but the script **stop** running after 1 or 2 hours from a new deployment or a new execution through the console (or some minutes, i don't know the exact timing). **Where** is the problem? Thanks for the help.

Example of *logs* on Heroku:

```
2020-07-15T10:47:40.500384+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python randobot.py` by user ________@gmail.com
2020-07-15T10:47:44.398310+00:00 heroku[run.1085]: State changed from starting to up
2020-07-15T10:47:44.455749+00:00 heroku[run.1085]: Awaiting client
2020-07-15T10:47:44.773283+00:00 heroku[run.1085]: Starting process with command `python\ randobot.py`
2020-07-15T10:47:50.709806+00:00 heroku[run.1085]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2020-07-15T10:47:51.233462+00:00 heroku[run.1085]: Process exited with status 129
2020-07-15T10:47:51.270855+00:00 heroku[run.1085]: State changed from up to complete
```

*Procfile.*:

```
web: python randobot.py
```

Code *randobot.py*:

```
import telebot
import time
import json

bot_token = "____________________________"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=bot_token)

...
... Some functions ...
...

while True: 
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
        time.sleep(15)
```

Commands used for the deploy on Heroku with git:

```
git add .
git commit -m "..."
git push heroku master
```

Command used the first time on Heroku to run the bot (after the login ecc.):

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, with (command on the console):

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```